# How to reschedule job immediately when i update CRON expression?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression, crontrigger

Firstly when i start job my cron expression is 0 0/10 * * * ? *(For Every 10 Minutes)
Eventually i have updated my cron expression to 0 0/2 * * * ? *(Updated for 2 minutes)

i want the update cron expression to take immediate effect instead of waiting until the event jobWasExecuted called.

Is it possible to reschedule as and when i update cron expression.

Thanks,
Kusuma

Comment: You can re-schedule the job: unschedule existing job and schedule with new cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its not achievable with CronTriggerBean. Instead you can use SimpleTriggerBean. Following is an example:

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" 
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="0" />

</bean>
```

By giving **startDelay** as 0 the job will start immediately the server is started. **repeatInterval** can be given based on your requirement.